# Can I combine a Deutsche Bahn city ticket with an RMV S-Bahn single ticket?

Tags: trains, tickets, germany, frankfurt, deutsche-bahn

I am travelling to Frankfurt on a Deutsche Bahn ICE train. I plan to get off at Frankfurt (Main) Hauptbahnhof and take an RMV S-Bahn or RE train to Frankfurt airport. The ICE ticket is a Sparpreis fare, and includes a city ticket.

However, the city ticket in Frankfurt [does not cover the airport](https://assets.static-bahn.de/dam/jcr:ef8a92ce-4c23-4680-9f7b-3f44d75f9690/cityticket_c57.pdf), and along the Frankfurt Hauptbahnhof - Frankfurt Flughafen Regionalbahnhof route, it appears to be valid up to Frankfurt Stadion.

So, when buying a ticket to the airport, can I buy an RMV single ticket from Frankfurt Stadion to Frankfurt Flughafen Regionalbahnhof and combine it with the city ticket, or do I need to buy a ticket from Frankfurt Hauptbahnhof? The price difference in this case is small, but I am curious to know what the general rules in such cases are.

Comment: Have you already bought your ticket? If not, just buy a ticket to Frankfurt Flughafen from wherever you are starting.

Comment: @KristvanBesien Thanks! In my initial search, I was only seeing options to transfer at other cities, which I wanted to avoid, but after seeing your comment I explicitly searched for transfers via Frankfurt Hbf and found a connecting ICE to Frankfurt Flughafen at no extra cost. So thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do that.

You don't "combine" tickets in the literal sense of the word, but you can certainly use them like you describe.

Several tickets can be used together on a single route, as long as the whole route is covered collectively by the tickets.

What you are doing here can be described as "split ticketing" (e.g. by seat61.com), and is a possible tactic to get lower fares on long distance routes. I guess the ICE Sparpreis is available to Frankfurt, but not FRA Airport in your case?

Comment: I am not sure about the RMV tariff, but as you write "split ticketing ... is a possible tactic to get lower fares" and is exactly therefore in many German regions not allowed. If you split a ticket, the conditions for carriage may require you to also physically get off the train and proceed with the next train at the station where the ticket is split instead of using any through services.

Comment: Thanks! The comment by @Tor-EinarJarnbjo is the key to my question, so is there any official place the confirms the possibility of this? (For my current trip I have [now got a single connecting ticket to the airport](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/170020/can-i-combine-a-deutsche-bahn-city-ticket-with-an-rmv-s-bahn-single-ticket#comment425081_170020), so this is just for future reference).

Comment: Also, to answer the last sentence, there was no direct connection to the airport, and I was only seeing transfers via other cities, which I wanted to avoid. But since posting my question, I searched for transfers explicitly via Frankfurt Hbf and found a connecting ICE to the airport from there for the same price. That works out well as I can simply buy an RMV ticket in case my first train is delayed and I miss the connection.

Comment: If your first train is delayed, you won't need to buy a second ticket. Just go to the information desk in Frankfurt Hauptbahnhof and get your ticket endorsed - in case of a delay on a ticket with Zugpreisbindung and a connection you are entitled to use any later trains from the connection point.